# Optimal training advice for 800 meter runner?

Tags: running, track-and-field

Background: Last year, I ran a 17:30 XC 5k, a 4:53 mile, a 2:08 800m and a 58s 400m. Using an age graded calculator, it appears my performance increases relatively up to the 800, and then drops off at the 4. In other words, 800 is my best event, and also happens to be the one I enjoy the most. I’ve been a distance runner since middle school, and used to train solely for the 16 and 8, with the occasional workout tailored to the 8, such as split 800s and 200’s. I’ve read that the 800 is beginning to be thought of more as a long sprint; after all, it uses about the same amount of anaerobic energy systems as aerobic.

I’ve taken it upon myself to train with the sprinters for the indoor season, weightlifting including weighted explosive half squats, arm swings, deadlifts, leg press among other things. We also run stairs a couple times a week: about 80 to 100 flights. Finally, this includes 30s hills with longer recoveries than I’m used to.

Question:
Am I training optimally for the 800, taking into account I have a relatively strong cardiovascular base from XC and all my prior distance running? Is this better suited for say, the 500?

P.S. I’m thinking about doing an indoor pentathlon for fun, as I have experience in all the events except 60m hurdles. It seems this training would be beneficial?